# How can I create a new object from import class

Tags: clojure

I have imported the firestore snapshot and trying to create it's object

```
(:import [com.google.cloud.firestore
        QueryDocumentSnapshot])
(def snapshot1 (QueryDocumentSnapshot.toObject. [:reference "user1" :type "Promotion" :included-scans 100]))
```

But it compile failed and error is :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: QueryDocumentSnapshot.toObject,
```

Can you please help me to create a new object for that class **QueryDocumentSnapshot** ?

Comment: I bet that your import statement has to go into your namespace declaration. Like `(ns some-namespace (:import com.google.cloud.forestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot))`.

Comment: @Joshua yes, the import is inside the namespace absolutely.

Answer (score 2):

You can call a constructor like

`(QueryDocumentSnapshot. whatever-arguments)`

But QueryDocumentSnapshot has no public constructor and [looking at the source](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/blob/master/google-cloud-firestore/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/firestore/QueryDocumentSnapshot.java) it can only be instantiated using a static factory method like such:

`(QueryDocumentSnapshot/fromDocument firestore timestamp document)`

I'm not sure what you're actually trying to achieve here but it doesn't look like you can do what you think you can do to that class.

Comment: Hi, I supposed that we can use the public method "toObject" of it.
But can you advise how to create an object for that class?

Comment: `toObject` is instance method. You have to create `QueryDocumentSnapshot` with the `fromDocument` factory method and then call `toObject` on it: `(.toObject (QueryDocumentSnapshot/fromDocument firestore timestamp document))`

Comment: Thanks @AlešRoubíček however I have no the firestore object to put in.
I am trying the create the QueryDocumentSnapshot object from a hashmap.

Comment: could not call the fromDocument neither:
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching method: fromDocument, compiling:`

Comment: @giahuy you're probably not passing in the right types of arguments to the fromDocument method. Since you have no firestore object, as you said, that would explain why. I'm still wondering what you're trying to achieve here. Are you writing some kind of test?

Comment: @JoostDiepenmaat it's correct bro. I am trying to write the unit test for this function:
`(defn get-scan-value
  [snapshot]
  (-> snapshot
    .getData
    (.get "scan")))`

And the input 'snapshot' is the QueryDocumentSnapshot object

Comment: Since you need a firebase instance to create a snapshot, you cannot really "unit test" that function (and I would argue it's pointless to create a unit test for it - the function does nothing useful on its own). Create an integration  test that uses a firebase implementation instead.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, after taking your and Joost's answers into consideration, I discovered something rather funny:

Your error message says, that the class `QueryDocumentSnapshot.toObject` cannot be found. There you have it.

If you want to call a static method, you have to write `(class/method args)`.

For more information on java interop I highly recommend the official documentation: https://clojure.org/reference/java_interop

Also, take Joost's comments on the class itself into consideration.